# Incorrect Notebook Name from Notebooks[]

Tags: notebooks, windows

I wanted to check if a notebook was open and warn the user before copying the file to a repository. This isn't the exact code, but it demonstrates the issue:

```
TableForm[(Information[#, "WindowTitle"] &) /@ Notebooks[]]
```

Most of the notebooks appear correctly. But one notebook is being petulant and doesn't report the file name displayed in the title:

[image: image of oddball notebook]

The hash like string appears in place of the filename doesn't match the filename in the Notebook and none of the properties can be accessed using "Information".
I suspect it is related to OneDrive, but **all** the files are stored in folder linked to OneDrive. This is the only Notebook which has a result of this form.

*Has anyone seen anything like this?*

(Before i submit to the support staff at Wolfram)

"12.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"

Comment: All of my notebooks are stored in OneDrive. I am using version 12.3, and I get the correct list of notebooks, without any error.

Comment: Are there special characters (or some other distinguishing feature) of the notebook that mis-behaves?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and questions. No special characters: Letters, Numbers, _, -.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a possible malformed notebook. I had modified a notebook file by adding a comment at the top of the notebook programmatically. The odd hash like string was the UUID. So it's probably my fault! I will close the question.
Thanks for your time folks!
Mark